# Crawling too many links at the same time

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a website and my spider (I don't know why) is crawling my links in such disorder!!

It's crawling all the links I want but it stored only the first one (rank and url_seller as example after)... I'm new in this universe of crawling, python or scrapy but all I want is to learn!! I post my code here, somebody could help me ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
import numbers
from MarketplacePulse.items import MarketplacepulseItem
import urllib.parse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MarketplacePulseSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'MP_A_UK'
    allowed_domains = ['marketplacepulse.com', 'amazon.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.marketplacepulse.com/amazon/uk']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MarketplacepulseItem()

        rank = response.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class="number"]/text()').extract()
        print('\n', rank, '\n')
        url_1 = response.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
        print('\n', url_1, '\n')
        for i in range(len(rank)-2):
            item['month_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i]).strip()
            item['year_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i+1]).strip()
            item['lifetime_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i+2]).strip()
            i += 3

        for i in range(len(url_1)):
            url_tmp = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.marketplacepulse.com',url_1[i])
            yield scrapy.Request(url_tmp, callback=self.parse_2, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        url_2 = response.xpath('//body/div/section/div/div/div/p/a[contains(text(), "Amazon.co.uk")]/@href').extract()

        item['url_seller'] = ''.join(url_2).strip()
        yield scrapy.Request(str(url_2), callback=self.parse_3, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_3(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        business_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="a-row a-spacing-medium"]/div[@class="a-column a-span6"]/ul[@class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"]/li//span[@class="a-list-item"]/span[.="Business Name:"]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
        phone_number = response.xpath('//div[@class="a-column a-span6"]/ul[@class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"]/li//span[@class="a-list-item"]/span[.="Phone number:"]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
        address = response.xpath('//div[@class="a-column a-span6"]/ul[@class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"]/li//span[span[contains(.,"Address:")]]/ul//li//text()').extract()

        item['business_name'] = ''.join(business_name).strip()
        item['phone_number'] = ''.join(phone_number).strip()
        item['address'] = '\n'.join(address).strip()
        yield item
```

I post also an example of what I want and of what I get... you'll see the problem I hope!!

What I want :

```
2017-07-18 11:28:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&orderID=&seller=A7CL6GT0UVQKS&tab=&vasStoreID=>
{'address': '55740 Currant Rd\nMishawaka\nIndiana\n46545\nUS',
 'business_name': 'Better World Books Marketplace Inc',
 'lifetime_rank': '863',
 'month_rank': '218',
 'phone_number': '',
 'url_seller': 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aag/main?seller=A7CL6GT0UVQKS&tag=mk4343k-21',
 'year_rank': '100'}
2017-07-18 11:28:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&orderID=&seller=W5VG5JB9GHYUG&tab=&vasStoreID=>
{'address': 'ROOM 919, BLOCK 2 West, SEG TECHNOLOGY PARK\n'
            'SHENZHEN\n'
            'GUANGDONG\n'
            '518000\n'
            'CN\n'
            'FU TIAN QU QIAO XIANG LU HAO FENG YUAN 7 DONG 7A\n'
            'SHENZHEN\n'
            'GUANGDONG\n'
            '518000\n'
            'CN',
 'business_name': 'MUDDER TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD',
 'lifetime_rank': '3',
 'month_rank': '28',
 'phone_number': '86 18565729081',
 'url_seller': 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aag/main?seller=W5VG5JB9GHYUG&tag=mk4343k-21',
 'year_rank': '10'}
```

And what I get :

```
2017-07-18 11:28:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&orderID=&seller=A20T907OQC02JJ&tab=&vasStoreID=>
{'address': '55740 Currant Rd\nMishawaka\nIndiana\n46545\nUS',
 'business_name': 'Better World Books Marketplace Inc',
 'lifetime_rank': '863',
 'month_rank': '218',
 'phone_number': '',
 'url_seller': 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aag/main?seller=A7CL6GT0UVQKS&tag=mk4343k-21',
 'year_rank': '100'}
2017-07-18 11:28:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&orderID=&seller=A1XG2K8M6HRQZ8&tab=&vasStoreID=>
{'address': 'ROOM 919, BLOCK 2 West, SEG TECHNOLOGY PARK\n'
            'SHENZHEN\n'
            'GUANGDONG\n'
            '518000\n'
            'CN\n'
            'FU TIAN QU QIAO XIANG LU HAO FENG YUAN 7 DONG 7A\n'
            'SHENZHEN\n'
            'GUANGDONG\n'
            '518000\n'
            'CN',
 'business_name': 'MUDDER TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD',
 'lifetime_rank': '863',
 'month_rank': '218',
 'phone_number': '86 18565729081',
 'url_seller': 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aag/main?seller=A7CL6GT0UVQKS&tag=mk4343k-21',
 'year_rank': '100'}
```

You can see that the url_seller are exactly the same and the rank (by month, year or lifetime) also... but I want them to be different..... And the url_seller is not the same that the link I crawled, but it has to be the same..... Any help please?

Comment: What do you get if you print the contents of `url_2` immediately after you've collected it by xpath?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer but the website I try to crawl always give me the same output : `INFO: Ignoring response <404 link>`, which mean (I think) that I cannot crawl it anymore...

Comment: Does it mean that my spider cannot find the website I want? That's strange because I'm sure the link is the good one...

Comment: If you go to the same address that your spider is trying to crawl in a browser, do you still get a 404?

Comment: No I don't, that's why it's really strange...

Comment: Ok, never mind!! Thanks a lot for your help below and don't worry, I'll find a way to figure this problem out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ranking issues

I'll walk through it step by step:

- You get a list of rank numbers:

  ```
  rank = response.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class="number"]/text()').extract()
  ```
- You get a list of URLs:

  ```
  url_1 = response.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
  ```
- Here's where you go wrong:

  ```
  for i in range(len(rank)-2):
      item['month_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i]).strip()
      item['year_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i+1]).strip()
      item['lifetime_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i+2]).strip()
      i += 3
  ```

  Firstly, since you're using a for loop, your `i` variable is getting reset to the next item (in this case the next number) at the beginning of each loop, so you're looping through each one, not looping by threes. That `i += 3` is doing nothing, sorry.

  Anyway, the purpose of the loop appears to be to build the following structure:

  ```
  {'month_rank': <rank>, 'year_rank': <rank>, 'lifetime_rank': <rank>}
  ```

  So..., secondly, each time you run this loop, you overwrite the previous set of values without having done anything with them. Oops.
- You then proceed to loop through your list of URLs, passing the last set of rankings your previous loop built, along with each url to your `parse_2` function.

  ```
  for i in range(len(url_1)):
      url_tmp = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.marketplacepulse.com',url_1[i])
      yield scrapy.Request(url_tmp, callback=self.parse_2, meta={'item': item})
  ```

  You end up with each call to `parse_2` having the same set of ranking data.

To fix this, you should deal with your your URL and it's associated rankings in the same loop:

```
    for i in range(len(url_1)):
        url_tmp = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.marketplacepulse.com',url_1[i])

        item['month_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i*3]).strip()
        item['year_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i*3+1]).strip()
        item['lifetime_rank'] = ''.join(rank[i*3+2]).strip()

        yield scrapy.Request(url_tmp, callback=self.parse_2, meta={'item': item})
```

That should fix your rank issues.

---

## url_seller issue

I'm not too sure about the url_seller issue, because it seems like it should use the same url for both `item['url_seller']` and its call to `parse_3`, and it seems like it's using the right info to call `parse_3`, but continuing to use the same information in `item['url_seller']` over and over again.

I'm kind of going out on a limb here, since if I'm understanding the situation properly, both methods should (in the particular case that I think this is) make equal strings, but the only difference I've noticed so far is that for one you're using `''.join(url_2).strip()` and for the other you're using `str(url_2)`.

Since the part where you're using `str(url_2)` seems to be working properly where it's being used, perhaps you should try using it in the other spot too:

```
    item['url_seller'] = str(url_2)
```

Comment: Thanks!! A part is done thanks too you, I 'll continue to try fixing the rest but if you have some time (maybe not today), I'll be grateful to you!!

Comment: And just another thing : the `i` variable is increment by 3 each time? Even the first time? I mean, the first time, it'll be 1 2 3 or 1*3 2*3 3*3 ?

Comment: @P.Postrique In your original version, `i` started out as 0, then at the end of your loop it became 3, then at the start of the next loop it became 1, then at the end it became 4, etc. etc. etc...

Comment: In my version, `i` just increments by 1 each time, referencing which url it's on, while the `i*3`, `i*3+1`, i*3+2` references the associated ranks: `0, 1, 2` first, then `3, 4, 5`, etc...

Comment: This way `rank[0]`, `rank[1]`, and `rank[2]` are referenced when crawling `url_1[0]`, and `rank[3]`, `rank[4]`, and `rank[5]` are referenced when crawling `url_1[1]`, etc...

Comment: It was helpful but didn't help me entirely... Do I have to accept it anyway?

Comment: No, you don't have to, but if it helped you, then please at least upvote it if you're not going to accept it. You're choice.